# Need a count for a field from different timezones (have multiple fields from .csv uploaded file)

Tags: splunk, timestamp-with-timezone

I am little confused, as i have some events ingesting from .csv file in splunk from different different timezones china, pacific, eastern, europe etc...
I have fields like start time, end time, TimeZone, TimeZoneID, sitename, conferenceID & hostname.....etc

for your info(conferenceID=131146947830496273, 130855971227450408......)
was wondering if i have to do a ".......|stats count of conferenceID" for particular time interval(ex., 12:00 pm to 15:00 pm today ) by sitting on pacific timezone, using the start time and end time from the events search should collect all events sorting from there originating timezones time interval but not the taking splunk timezone time interval.

below are some samples of logs which I have

> testincsso,130878564690050083, Shona,"GMT-07:00, Pacific (San Francisco)",4,06/17/2019 09:33:17,06/17/2019 09:42:23,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,1,0,0,1,1
>   host = usloghost1.example.com sourcetype =webex_cdr
>   6/17/19
>   12:29:03.060 AM
>
> testincsso,129392485072911500,Meng,"GMT+08:00, China (Beijing)",45,06/17/2019 07:29:03,06/17/2019 07:59:22,31,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,30,1,1,0,0,1
>   host = usloghost1.corp.example.com sourcetype = webex_cdr
>   6/17/19
>   12:19:11.060 AM
>
> testincsso,131121310031953680,sarah ward,"GMT-07:00, Pacific (San Francisco)",4,06/17/2019 07:19:11,06/17/2019 07:52:54,34,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,34,3,3,0,0,2
>   host = usloghost1.corp.example.com sourcetype = webex_cdr
>   6/17/19
>   12:00:53.060 AM
>
> testincsso,130878909569842780,Patrick Janesch,"GMT+02:00, Europe (Amsterdam)",22,06/17/2019 07:00:53,06/17/2019 07:04:50,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,2,3,2,0,1,2
>   host = usloghost1.corp.example.com sourcetype = webex_cdr

update:

there is 2 fields in the events start time and end time for every conference it held in there local timezone(event originating TZ).
also _time refers the splunk time which I don't need in this case. what I need is there is date_hour, date_minutes, date_seconds...etc which shows events local timezone time(china, europe, asia...etc).
so when i sit here pacific TZ and try searching for 
index=test "testincsso" | stats count(conferenceID) by _time 
taking timeinterval last 4 hours then the output should display the count of Cenferences by taking the count from all events by comparing with there local TZ's time for last 4 hours.
so do I need to use "| eval hour = strftime(_time,"%H")" or "| eval mytime=_time | convert timeformat="%H ctime(mytime)" before stats.
thanks

-also changing timepicker default behavior may give correct results. 
I have events with fields "start time" and "end time" from different TZ. so when I try to search events ex., date range "06-16-2019" using time-picker I should get all events by seeing the field "start time" in events not the "_time" of Splunk.
I want change my splunk time picker default behavior and gives output by sieng events fields(ex., "start time" & "end time". below the query I changed in source xml.

index=test sourcetype=webex] "testinc" | eval earliest = $toearliest$ | eval latest=if($tolatest$ < 0, now(),$tolatest$) | eval datefield = strptime($Time$, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")|stats count(Conference)

Comment: Welcome to SO :) What exactly is the question? Try to format your question, that it is easily readable for us.

Comment: Thanks :) feel confident to be around with you guyz haha.. just updated question

Comment: got a chance to look?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any control over how the logs are generated, it's best to include the time zone as part of the timestamp.  For example, "06/17/2019 07:00:53+0200".  Then Splunk can easily convert the time.

If that's not an option, perhaps you can specify the time zone when the logs are read.  Assuming each log is stored on a system in the originating time zone, the props.conf stanza for the Universal Forwarder should include a `TZ` attribute telling Splunk where in the world the log is from.

If this doesn't help, please edit your question to say what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: got a chance to look?

Comment: Since you can't normalize the times before indexing, you'll have to do so at search time.  The means converting the timestamp to epoch form, interpreting the GMT offset, adjusting the epoch time by the offset, then using `stats` on the resulting time to get your results.

Comment: I am running this query but doesn't have any results display

index=test sourcetype=webex "testinc" | eval earliest = 1560582000| eval latest =if(1560668400 < 0, now(),1560668400) | eval _time = strptime("Start Time","%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") | where _time >=earliest AND _time <= latest | stats count(Conference)

Comment: Use single quotes around 'Start Time'.  Double quotes denote a string and "Start Time" does not match the time format given so `strptime` fails.